# React - send function to child via stateless component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I can send a function down to a class component with no problem. But when I want to pass down a function to a stateless component, and from there to a class component, something goes wrong.
It says "`this.props.getProduct is not a function`" , so I guess some binding thing has to be added, but I already did that in the top component.

The top component is like this:

```
class App extends Component { 

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      product: {}
    }

    this.getProduct = this.getProduct.bind(this)
  }

  getProduct(productId){

    const result = productlist.products.filter(obj => {
      return obj.id === productId;

    })
    this.setState({
      product: result[0]
    })

 }

  render() {

      const {product} = this.state

    return (

      <div className="App">

        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>

            <Route path="/" render={props =>
              <Main  
                getProduct = {this.getProduct}
                product = {this.state.product}
                {...props} 
              />}
            />

          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is "Main", the intermediate stateless component

```
const Main = (props) =>

  <Route path="/products/:product" render={ props =>
      <Product  
        getProduct={props.getProduct}
        product={props.product}
        {...props} 

      />}
  />
```

"Product" component where the error occurs

```
class Product extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.props.getProduct(this.props.match.params.product)           // "not a function"

  }
```

I suspect there is some kind of extra binding that needs to be done, but how?
Here is a sandbox where you can see the problem:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k358w154xv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a collision here:

```
  const Main = (props) =>

  <Route path="/products/:product" render={ props =>
      <Product  
        getProduct={props.getProduct}
        product={props.product}
        {...props} 

      />}
  />
```

props from Main and props in render, so when you are passing in props from it takes props from the render function you passed instead of props from Main. You have to rename one, or replace **const Main = (props)** with **const Main = ({ getProduct, product})** and then pass it to

Comment: If I make that change, it seems I also have to change the props to " getProduct={getProduct}" (omitting "props."), and then it works! Not sure I understand everyhting though..

Comment: Yes, ({ getProduct, product }) is short for (props) > { const getProduct = props.getProducts; etc...} otherwise just rename them to mainProps and routeProps for better clarity

Answer (score 1):

The `route` render function `props` argument is shadowing the `Main` component's `props` variable. Better change variable name of `render` argument

```
const Main = (props) =>

  <Route path="/products/:product" render={ p =>
      <Product  
        getProduct={props.getProduct}
        product={props.product}
        {...props} 

      />}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      product: {},
    }

    this.getProduct = this.getProduct.bind(this)
  }

  getProduct(productId) {

    const result = productlist.products.filter(obj => {
      return obj.id === productId

    })
    this.setState({
      product: result[0],
    })

  }

  render() {

    const { product } = this.state

    return (

      <div className="App">

        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>

            <Route
              path="/products/:product" render={props =>
              <Product
                getProduct={props.getProduct}
                product={props.product}
                {...props}

              />}
            />

          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```